# celery slow to start executing a task

Tags: python, celery

I'm using Redis as backend, with celery 4.1.  It seems pretty slow to start executing, can anyone offer ideas for why its happening, it looks like its taking 3 seconds to schedule the task to run.  As you can see from the log, it takes 3 seconds b/w receive and result, even though the task itself has finished in almost 0 seconds.

> [2018-05-15 18:32:41,659: INFO/MainProcess] **Received task**:
> consensus[6cfba08e-3c43-42ff-89c3-04f3ea0f4db9]
>
> [2018-05-15
> 18:32:41,770: DEBUG/MainProcess] **Task accepted**:
> consensus[6cfba08e-3c43-42ff-89c3-04f3ea0f4db9] pid:24922
>
> [2018-05-15
> 18:32:44,413: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] **Task
> consensus** [6cfba08e-3c43-42ff-89c3-04f3ea0f4db9] succeeded in
> 0.00187364500016s:

Comment: How did you end up resolving this?